# Import .csv and save with new values in powershell

Tags: import, cell, powershell-4.0

I have a .csv template with an empty column called URL. I would like to update it every time I get a value for its user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$file = "c:\Users\user\Documents\users.csv"

Import-Csv $file  -Delimiter ',' | % {

     $_.URL = $generated_url ; $_

} | Export-Csv "c:\Users\user\Documents\users_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ',' -notype
```

This updates all of the cells with the same value. Is there a workaround?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to update just one row which corresponds to the current user.

To do that you have to select the row that has to be updated using the `where-object` clause

```
param(
 $username
)

$file = "c:\Users\user\Documents\users.csv"

Import-Csv $file  -Delimiter ',' | Where {$_.username -like $username} | % {

 $_.URL = $generated_url ; $_

} | Export-Csv "c:\Users\user\Documents\users_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ',' -notype
```

To save the CSV as excel as asked in the comment below, the best option is to save as CSV as above. Then use Excel COM libraries to convert it.

**Example**

```
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $False
$Excel.displayalerts=$False
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($CSVFileName)
$Workbook.SaveAs($Excelfilename,1)
$Excel.Quit()
If(ps excel){
  kill -name excel
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. So simple.. But my issue now is that when I do that for two users, every time it creates a new csv that includes only that one specific user. Is there a way to update the existing csv file? Thanks

Comment: I had to use the -append at the end. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would it be possible to update an exccel spreadsheet with those values? Rather exporting it in to a new csv

Comment: You can use Excel COM libraries to open and Save as xls . See code edit above